# Left and right DIV sections not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, web

Side by side picture of problem: [image]

My website is http://berathen.com
For what ever reason everything looks to work just fine in IE, Firefox, and Chrome, but not in Safari. For some reason my left and right div sections join together at the center.

```
#leftSide
{
  position: relative;
  left: -350px;
  max-width: 320px;
}

#rightSide
{
  position: relative;
  left: 650px;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent few minutes inspecting your site in an old version of safari.

When i tried to apply `left:0` to `#outerBox2` inside `#leftSide`, It in turn brought the right box to left side as well, which is when i noticed that your `HTML` is invalid - You have multiple elements with id `outerBox2` (*`id` should be unique in a document, You can use class instead to apply common stuff*).

Which i think is causing the problem and fixing it might solve the issue.

Anyway, Few other things i noticed while inspecting (*might or might not help you*)...

- The  content of `div#leftSide` is `position:fixed`, hence it has a height of 0px. You might not even need it.
- You've manually appled `width` and `height` equla to `0`. I wonder why! (*You might not need that as well then..?*)
- The content in middle does not have a container, or wrapper. If it has one, it's easy to apply `padding` or `margin` to both sides and absolutely position the left and right content or float them `left` and `right` respectively.

*Side note: By seeing all this i was wondering how this works in modern browsers... i'd just say they're being too kind towards you... :)*

Comment: Thanks! I gave each box its own ID and set their 'left' to the amount needed to place them where I wanted them on the screen. Now everything looks to work in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```
#leftSide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 320px;
}
```

I don't think safari picks up negative `left` if `position` is `relative`.